# Dragging on grid does not work well if the content is scaled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have one big table with many `draggable` tables in. If the content scaling is set to 1, everything works fine, but after the user changes scaling, drag on the grid does not work well. Tables jump out of the virtual grid and it causes problems even after the scale is set back to 1. How do I fix this problem, so that after scaling virtual drag grid scales as well? Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/um18ospL/1/

Drag the tables. Then scroll with the mouse wheel to change scale. Drag again and you will see the problem.

```js
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
 var blockId = "channel"+i;
 var aspect = "16:9";
  var aspX = parseInt(aspect.split(':')[0]);
  var aspY = parseInt(aspect.split(':')[1]);
  var width = $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.vid').width();
  var height = $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.vid').height();
  var test = (width/aspX)*aspY;
  var test2 = (height/aspY)*aspX;
  if(test <= height){
    $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.placeHolder').css({'height': test+'px'});
  }
  else {
    $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.placeHolder').css({'width': test2+'px'});
  }
}

$('.channels').draggable({
  containment: $('.screens'),
  stack: '.channels',
  grid: [200, 200],
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
  },
  drag: function(){
  },
  stop: function(){
  }
})

var current = {x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 1};
var max = 5, min = 0.1;
document.getElementById("mainContainer").addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = e.pageX,
                y = e.pageY,
                coef = e.deltaY > 0 ? 0.7 : 1.2,
                nz = current.zoom * coef,
                cx = x - (x - current.x) * coef,
                cy = y - (y - current.y) * coef;
            if (nz < max && nz > min) {
            current.zoom = nz;
            current.x = cx;
            current.y = cy;
            this.style.transform
                = 'translate('+cx+'px, '+cy+'px) '
                + 'scale('+nz+')';
                }
            if(nz != 1){
              $('.screens').css({'border':'3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
            }
            else {
              $('.screens').css({'border':'none'});
            }
            return;
        });
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#leftDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
}

#displayItems {
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 3px;
    /*resize: vertical;*/
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

#menu li span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li ul li {
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    cursor: move;
}

#menu li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#settingsDiv {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3px;
}

.channel {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.thClass {
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.channel tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#settingsDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.settings {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
    display: block;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background: url(images/comment-rowsubmit.png) repeat-x;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.addList{
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.addList:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: antiquewhite;
}

.draggableItems {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(images/comment-bg.png) repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: url(images/bg-tabs.png) repeat;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background: linear-gradient(left, #22ADD4, #1E98BA);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
 max-width: 100px;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}

.ui-resizable {
 position: absolute !important;
 width: 250px;
}

#mainDiv .container {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
}

#mainContainer {
 width: 1926px;
 height: 1086px;
}

#dispInfo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png);
}

.videoDropped {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}

.screens{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.channels {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
 background: url(images/rsz_buttons.png);
 background-size: cover;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 22px;
 color: #b8c0c8;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.btn:hover {
 background: url(images/hover_buttons.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.cpu {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 7px;
}

.cpu:hover {
  resize: both;
}

/*Audio styling*/

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 30%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 13%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 20%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 30%;
}

.level4 {
  top: 45%;
}

.level5 {
  top: 61%;
}

.level6 {
  top: 78%;
}

.level7 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 15%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 53%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
  overflow: hidden;
}

.audioRight {
  left: 71%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 200%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}

#mainContainer {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
}

.placeHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <div id="deviceInfo">
            <ul id="menu">
            <li>Device Name
                <ul id="deviceName">
                    <li>
                      item 1
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Interface
                <ul id="interface">
                    <li>
                      item 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="settingsDiv">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
      <div id="mainContainer" class="ui-droppable"><table class="screens ui-draggable" dispcoords="0x0" dispresolution="1920x1080" style="position: relative;"><tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="screensRow ui-draggable-handle"><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"><table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 478px; height: 358px; font-size: 11px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative; margin-top: -179px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">            <tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="channelName ui-draggable-handle" id="channel1" audiopid="0x33" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:0x33,width:0,height:0,language:geo" interface="192.168.222.38" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="Imedi" serviceprovider="Stereo +" videopid="0x31" videostream="format:H264,type:video,pid:0x31,width:1920,height:1080" aspect="16:9" fps="25">Imedi</td><td colspan="2" class="channelNumber ui-draggable-handle">1</td>            </tr>            <tr class="audioVideo ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="vid ui-draggable-handle"><div class="placeHolder ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 236.813px;"></div></td><td colspan="2" class="sound ui-draggable-handle"><div class="audiodb ui-draggable-handle">              <div class="audioNumbers ui-draggable-handle">                <span class="db max level0 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">0</p></span>                <span class="db high level1 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-6</p></span>                <span class="db level2 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-12</p></span>                <span class="db normal level3 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-20</p></span>                <span class="db level4 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-30</p></span>                <span class="db level5 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-40</p></span>                <span class="db level6 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-50</p></span>                <span class="db low level7 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-60</p></span>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioLeft ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioRight ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <span class="levels level0 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level1 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level2 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level3 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level4 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level5 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level6 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level7 ui-draggable-handle"></span>            </div></td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfo ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolution ui-draggable-handle">Resolution</td><td class="aspect ui-draggable-handle">Aspect</td><td class="fps ui-draggable-handle">FPS</td><td class="vformat ui-draggable-handle">V-Format</td><td class="aformat ui-draggable-handle">A-Format</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">L</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">R</td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfoValues ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolValue ui-draggable-handle">1920x1080</td><td class="aspectValue ui-draggable-handle">16:9</td><td class="fpsValue ui-draggable-handle">25</td><td class="vformatValue ui-draggable-handle">H264</td><td class="aformatValue ui-draggable-handle">MP2</td><td class="leftBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td><td class="rightBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td>            </tr>          </tbody><div class="resize-sensor ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div class="resize-sensor-expand ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div><div class="resize-sensor-shrink ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div></table></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"><table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 478px; height: 358px; font-size: 11px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative; margin-top: -179px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">            <tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="channelName ui-draggable-handle" id="channel2" audiopid="0x33" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:0x33,width:0,height:0,language:geo" interface="192.168.222.38" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.103" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="720x576" serviceid="3" servicename="RUSTAVI 2" serviceprovider="Stereo +" videopid="0x31" videostream="format:H264,type:video,pid:0x31,width:720,height:576" aspect="15:11" fps="25">RUSTAVI 2</td><td colspan="2" class="channelNumber ui-draggable-handle">2</td>            </tr>            <tr class="audioVideo ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="vid ui-draggable-handle"><div class="placeHolder ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 383.182px;"></div></td><td colspan="2" class="sound ui-draggable-handle"><div class="audiodb ui-draggable-handle">              <div class="audioNumbers ui-draggable-handle">                <span class="db max level0 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">0</p></span>                <span class="db high level1 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-6</p></span>                <span class="db level2 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-12</p></span>                <span class="db normal level3 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-20</p></span>                <span class="db level4 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-30</p></span>                <span class="db level5 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-40</p></span>                <span class="db level6 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-50</p></span>                <span class="db low level7 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-60</p></span>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioLeft ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioRight ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <span class="levels level0 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level1 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level2 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level3 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level4 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level5 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level6 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level7 ui-draggable-handle"></span>            </div></td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfo ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolution ui-draggable-handle">Resolution</td><td class="aspect ui-draggable-handle">Aspect</td><td class="fps ui-draggable-handle">FPS</td><td class="vformat ui-draggable-handle">V-Format</td><td class="aformat ui-draggable-handle">A-Format</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">L</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">R</td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfoValues ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolValue ui-draggable-handle">720x576</td><td class="aspectValue ui-draggable-handle">15:11</td><td class="fpsValue ui-draggable-handle">25</td><td class="vformatValue ui-draggable-handle">H264</td><td class="aformatValue ui-draggable-handle">MP2</td><td class="leftBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td><td class="rightBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td>            </tr>          </tbody><div class="resize-sensor ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div class="resize-sensor-expand ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div><div class="resize-sensor-shrink ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div></table></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td></tr><tr class="screensRow ui-draggable-handle"><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>   
</div>
```